# How do I get the source URL of the data being recv'd through a socket?

Tags: c++, http, sockets, proxy, winsock

I thought about keeping track of redirects because they would have the next URL in the header until I get a HTTP200 ok, then I would have the FQDN of the source of the 200.

But I don't think that is how a browser does it, my proxy can do a hard redirect of the browser request, but the browser displays the correct URL of the redirected data without having received any HTTP301's.

I want to know what the browser does to get the source of its data and then do that in winsock. Anyone?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "hard" redirect-- all HTTP/3xx redirections work the same way. The browser only shows the URLs that it knows about, which is either the URL it tried to load originally, or the URL loaded when the browser chased down a HTTP/3xx redirect (see the Location header). If the browser is navigated by JavaScript or a Meta Refresh, the browser itself has that URL to start with.

Comment: And no, from any given socket, you cannot determine the URL. You can only determine the URL based on what you yourself asked the socket to give you (in the HTTP request you sent on the socket). Zooming out to the 1000 ft level, what are you really trying to do, overall?

Comment: Fair enough I'm inventing my own terminology, by "hard" redirect I simply mean taking the browsers' request and replacing it with a totally different request without the use of any headers. I want the ability to filter incoming connections by hostname, before my browser sees it - that is all.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are "replacing it" without "use of any headers." Unless HTTP redirect headers are returned to the client, then the client has *no* awareness of any change in the URL. You might want to use Fiddler to see that your code works the way you think it does.

Comment: In my local proxy, I can accept the browser request, delete that request and forward something else entirely. The browser is not informed in any way that this has happened (no header returned through the socket). When I pass the alternate response back to the browser (client), it shows the correct URL for the HTTP data having only received the 200 header. How?

Comment: Like @EricLaw-MSFT said, use Fiddler (or a packet sniffer, like Wireshark) to see exactly what is being sent back to the browser.  Chances are, there is an extra header present, such as `Content-Location` or similar.

Comment: I had a look at the HTTP200 header for the particular site that I was testing this on and it has an 'X-Pingback:' field that contains the format 'http://website.com/xmlrpc.php' . This must be how the browser knows where it is eventually.

Comment: @Philip: No, that's not what happens. The browser address bar only shows the URL that it knows about. It will NOT pull the value from any other header (that would be a major security vulnerability).

Comment: In that case the only other possibility is that google Chrome parses the page content and does a reverse lookup to match the URL.

Comment: By the way I don't understand why this question is getting downvoted. There just seems to be a hostile tone and no solution offered here. What's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Winsock solution to my question is to use the `getpeername()` function after `connect()`'ing to a remote connection. That should return IP:Port info from which I can get the hostname at least.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the browser does, it win't retrieve the information from the winsock layer: the sockets only travel in IP addresses and ports. I don't really know much about winsock (I'm UNIX guy) but it seems to sufficiently similar to UNIX socket layer to be quite sure that any transport level information is coming from a higher level abstraction. If you look at the [OSI model]{http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model} you see that winsocks is addressing level 5 while the thing you are looking for are level 7. The API typically stay within thecorresponding level. This view seems to be backed up by the [winsock FAQ]{http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#appproto}.

Comment: Your reply is useful, but the application layer still needs all info to pass through the lower layers to determine which url to display. Where amongst a success header and data is the source url?

Comment: There is no source URL in the response headers (unless the headers include a `Content-Location` header, which is very rare).  The application has to keep track of the URL it requests, and then update that URL when it changes.

Comment: @PhilipLangford: the winsock layer doesn't have an inkling that it the URL got redirected! It connected to some server address (IP number and port), received a couple of bytes which turn out in the application layer that it is a redirection, and it does another connection to another address. If the redirection happened transparently on a proxy, it seems to the socket layer as if the connection was still made to the target address!

Comment: @DietmarKühl That's a good point and I'll have to take the risk of  'getpeername()' returning the socket id of transparent proxies that do "hard"(sic) redirects. Hopefully, most servers follow proper protocol and send back a 301 or similar up until the target.

Answer (score 0):

Not all HTTP redirects result in a URL change.  A `301` redirect certainly does, but other `3xx` redirects do not.  If a browser receives a redirect other than `301`, it may decide whether to continue displaying the original URL or to display the new redirected URL.

Comment: 301, 302, 303, and 307 are the redirect codes, and all of these can change the URL or keep it the same. If you keep it the same, you're like to end in an endless redirect loop.

Comment: According to RFC 2616 Section 10.3, a `301` redirect means the requested URL is no longer valid for that resource and the supplied URL must be used for subsequent requests for that same resource.  Any other `3xx` redirect is temporary, and as such the requested URL is still valid for that resource and should continue being used for future requests for that same resource.

Comment: Yes, that's what the RFC says. In reality, no browser behaves that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to redirect without a 301. There's also 302. There's the element

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://foo.com/">
```

Finally, there's JavaScript:

```
<html><head><script language="javascript">    
window.location.href = "http://www.bar.com";
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: I need to know how 'window.location.href' is implemented at the low level

Comment: Changing the `window.location.href` causes a new HTTP request to be sent to the specified URL, same as if the user had typed in the URL into the browser's address bar.

Comment: So does a 30x-based redirect.